# How to unit test the store onInit using jest and angular

Tags: angular, jestjs, sonarqube

How to unit test the store the following using jest and angular, sonarqude is not covering this line. Thank you for response

In my component.ts

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
 this.store
      .select(studentfilesGetData)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe(studentFiles => {
        this.studentFiles = this.getSortedEmployerFiles(studentFiles );
      });
}
```

In my component.spec.ts

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    store = mock(Store);
      component = new myComponent(instance(store));
    when(store.select(studentfilesGetData)).thenReturn(of(studentFiles));
  });

  describe('ngOnInit', () => {
    test('should create', () => {
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `ngOnInit` is not being ran in your test.

Try explicitly calling it:

```
test('should set studentFiles', () => {
  component.ngOnInit();
  expect(component.studentFiles).toBeTruthy(); // can do your own assertions
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to test the result in your `.subscribe` callback method:

```
const valToCheck = ...

store
    .pipe(select(studentfilesGetData), takeUntil(this.destroy$))
    .subscribe(studentFiles => expect(valToCheck).toBe(component.getSortedEmployerFiles(studentFiles))
```